# PDF documents,open and load issue

Tags: pdf

We load Embedded documents into an Access database. We are inserting documents into a SQL back end.

Command we use: `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdInsertObject`

This works on most of the laptops using the database, but the newer laptops will not load or open any PDF documents.

We can load ANY other type of file, but when trying to load or open an existing PDF file the laptops "Hang" and you have to use `Ctrl + Alt + Delete`.  When pressing `Ctrl + Alt + Delete`, there are two background processes for 
Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (32 bit)

If you stop these processes you can carry on working, and it then gives an error:

```
A problem occured while Microsoft Access was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control
```

I have tried everything, re-installed MS Office 2010, Reinstall Adobe, Reinstall Photo Editor. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after MANY wasted hours.

I had installed Office 365 and it automatically installed Acrobat Adobe DC Reader, which is a Cloud application.

I uninstalled Adobe DC completely and then installed Acrobat Adobe 10 reader, which is still Freeware.

Everything works OK now!!!

Apparently you can have both installed.  First uninstall both, then load the older version.  When you then install Adobe DC, there is an option to keep the older version.  For now I am not installing Adobe DC unless I have to!!